# HTML entities in Pinterest pin descriptions

Tags: pinterest

(Posting this here since the form at https://developers.pinterest.com/support/contact/ doesn't work.)

I'm using the `data-pin-description` attribute on images on my site. I noticed that, when clicking the 'Pin it' button, the Pinterest overlay shows HTML entities in some of the pin descriptions (specifically for double and single quotes: `&quot;` and `&#39;`). Some of the pin descriptions in the overlay do have correctly displayed HTML entities. You can see an example on http://www.textillia.com/patterns/my-dogs-are-barking-row-row, the 'Pin it' button is at the bottom of the right column.

Is this a problem on Pinterest's end, or can I do something on my side to correct this?